# How to append String in freemarker template

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I have situation where I have to append the String to the variable in the freemarker template.

for example:

I have have list of objects and each returning specific values so that I can store these values in freemarker declare object and passed it to javascript function later in the template.

here is some code snippet:

```
// This is the list of items
[#list itemsList as item]

//here I am getting the object that I wanted to add in the template object
[#object = item.getObject()!]

//This is how I would like to append the object
[# itemsToAppendTo = "<div class="subs" id="til2"" + ${object} + "</div>"

[/#list]

//finally once loop finishes I would like to send the object to javascript

<script>

 // A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var html = ${itemsToAppendTo}

  $('.gTA').append( html ) 

});
```

Also, please provide suggestion if there is any better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate the output as usual, capture it into a variable (`html`), then print it into the JavaScript part.

```
<#assign html>
  <#list items as item>
    <div ...>${item.object}</div>
  </#list>
</#assign>
...
<#-- Attention: Remove ?markup_string if you aren't using any output format! -->
var html = "${html?markup_string?js_string}";
```

`?markup_string` is only needed if you are using `HTML`/`XML`/`XHTML` [output format](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html) (or any other markup output format). If you aren't using any, it will fail saying that the left-hand operand was a string, so you will know.

The `?js_string` ensures that quotation marks and such will be escaped with backslash.

Note that you can also append to a string like this:

```
<#assign s = 'foo'>
<#assign s += 'bar'>
${s} <#-- foobar -->
```

but it's less practical I guess (and slower if you append for many times).

Comment: great! looks like a good solution, btw how many characters we can set in the freemarker object. I believe there must be limit after which it will truncate the string.

Comment: There are no limits as far as FreeMarker is concerned, but Java has limits. So it should be around 2147483647 characters.

Comment: One more quick question, how do I render this object as html and at the same time store it as variable.

Comment: When you have it captured into `html` variable, you can just print it with `${html}`. In case you are in the nested content of `#escape`, you will have to write `<#noescape>${html}</#noescape>` though, to prevent double escaping. (If you are using auto-escaping via an output format, FreeMarker will know that it need not escape `html` again.)